# Java.Security.cert.certificateexception

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

I have byte array of a certificate.When i am converting it into X509 certificate it gives error :

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException

I have tried every thing but didn't find any answer please help.

My code :

```
CertificateFactory certfactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream(a);
X509Certificate cert=(X509Certificate)certfactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

When i use

```
CertificateFactory certfactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");
```

It removes error but cert is always **null**.

Please help me i am stuck in this about 3 days.
Thanks.

Comment: Improved your format code please...

Comment: I am new please explain a little bit.